# Android Main Thread/UI thread blocked despite using AsyncTask(Read similar posts but I am not satisfied with those)

Tags: android, android-asynctask, background, rx-java

I am doing a kind of File Manager where I want to fetch all the Files from `external or internal storage(files like APK, images, videos etc)` and then I am binding this fetched data on a `recycler view`, I have used `asyncTask` to perform this operation this is working fine when running when I am running my app on emulator because files are very few but when I am running this app on real device then it hangs the screen for 40-50 seconds after that update the UI
Here is my code

```
protected ArrayList<Integer> getFile(File dir) {
    File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
    Log.i(">>Files", "getFile: " + Arrays.toString(dir.listFiles()));
    if (listFile != null && listFile.length > 0) {
        for (File aListFile : listFile) {
            if (aListFile.isDirectory()) {
                fileList.add(aListFile);
                getFile(aListFile);
            } else {
                if (aListFile.getName().endsWith(".png")) {
                    Log.i(">>Image", "getFile: " + aListFile.getName());
                    pngImageList.add(aListFile);
                } else if (aListFile.getName().endsWith(".jpg") || aListFile.getName().endsWith(".jpeg")) {
                    jpegImageList.add(aListFile);
                } else if (aListFile.getName().endsWith(".gif")) {
                    gifList.add(aListFile);
                } else if (aListFile.getName().endsWith(".pptx") || aListFile.getName().endsWith(".ppt")) {
                    pptxList.add(aListFile);
                } else if (aListFile.getName().endsWith(".docx") || aListFile.getName().endsWith(".doc")) {
                    docxList.add(aListFile);
                } else if (aListFile.getName().endsWith(".pdf")) {
                    pdfList.add(aListFile);
                } else if (aListFile.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
                    txtList.add(aListFile);
                } else if (aListFile.getName().endsWith(".apk")) {
                    apkList.add(aListFile);
                }

            }
        }


    }

    return fileSizes;
}
```

and calling this function in `asyncTask's doInBackground` like this

```
 @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        getFile(file);
        return null;
    }
```

and after that I am binding this fetched data in `onPostExecute` method like this

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        showDialog(false);
        takeAway.add(pngImageList);
        takeAway.add(jpegImageList);
        takeAway.add(gifList);
        takeAway.add(pptxList);
        takeAway.add(docxList);
        takeAway.add(pdfList);
        takeAway.add(txtList);
        takeAway.add(apkList);

        lLayout = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 3);
        insightList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        insightList.setLayoutManager(lLayout);
        insightAdapter = new InsightAdapter(getActivity(), takeAway,COLORFUL_COLORS1);
        insightList.setAdapter(insightAdapter);
        insightAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();}
```

I have tried to use RX JAVA too here but didn't succeed because even then I have to use asyncTask to fetch all the files 
Any help or suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: post complete code

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh What else do you need? I have written complete code Calling asyncTask in `onCreate()`  like `new myAsyncTask.execute();` after that, all code I have posted I just want a way to perform this work in the background may be using `ThreadPoolExecuter` but don't know how to do that

Comment: put along in post created at top and see when is it triggered

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh sorry an not getting you :-/

Comment: I mean probably the code in post execute is taking the time on UI thread

Comment: what should I do then? because there is no heavy operation in `onPostExecute` method it is just showing fetched data from `doInBackground`

Comment: use logs to see or debug your code to see the time consuming code

Answer (score 0):

I think you should update adapter instead of re-creating in onPostExecute.

Comment: can you please explain it more? :-| if am not wrong `onPostExecute` is called only once when all work is done in `doInBackground` so how can I recreate it?